# disable jquery function if larger than mobile screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery, checking for window width and firing a function based on the screen size. Everything working as should so far. My issue is if the user starts on tablet / desktop and shrinks viewport to the size I want function to fire it works as should but when they bring screen size back to tablet / desktop the function still runs which is what I do not want. Is there a way to disable or kill the function?

jquery:

```
    $(document.ready(function(){

 $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        checkForMobile();
    });

    checkForMobile();

    function checkForMobile() {
        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (newWindowWidth < 768) {
            //append nav item to bottom of list mobile and active
            $($threePanelNav).click(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.appendTo($this.parent());
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Logic is backwards. Do the width check inside the click handler instead

Comment: @charlietfl so if else statement inside click event?...do you have an example? would be much appreciated..thanks for advice :)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using .net framework then in back-end code you can get the device type using the below code - (Code written in VB.Net/C# you can convert it as per your need)

"IsMobileBrowser" function to detect whether the device is mobile or not.

**C# :-**

```
private string[] mobileDevices = new string[] { "iphone", "ppc", "windows ce", "blackberry", "opera mini", "mobile", "palm", "portable", "opera mobi", "mobi" };

    public bool IsMobileBrowser(HttpRequest Request)
    {
        bool isMobile = false;
        var strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
        if (!IsNothing(strUserAgent))
        {
            if ((Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice | mobileDevices.Any(n => strUserAgent.Contains(n))))
                isMobile = true;
        }

        return isMobile;
    }
```

**VB.Net:-**

```
Dim mobileDevices As String() = New String() {
"iphone", "ppc", "windows ce", "blackberry",
"opera mini", "mobile", "palm", "portable", "opera mobi", "mobi"}

Public Function IsMobileBrowser(ByVal Request As HttpRequest) As Boolean
Dim isMobile As Boolean = False
Dim strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower()
If Not IsNothing(strUserAgent) Then
If (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Or
mobileDevices.Any(Function(n) strUserAgent.Contains(n))) Then
isMobile = True
End If
End If
Return isMobile
End Function
```

**THEN -**

If IsMobileBrowser(Request) returns true then its a mobile device and you can do the action.

**Here Request belongs to HTTP request object.**

*Hope this would help you.*

Comment: Question is not tagged as .NET. Also won't help if I am using a desktop but displaying smaller window